# Is $ \left\{\cup _{n \in \mathbb{N} } (x, x^n) \mid x \in [0,1] \right\} $ compact?

Tags: compactness

Is $$  \left\{\cup _{n \in \mathbb{N} } (x, x^n) \mid x \in [0,1] \right\}  $$ compact? My answer would be it isn't because it doesn't contain all its accumulation points ( for example the point $ (1/2,0) $)

Comment: Right: if compact, then closed and bounded. If not closed, then not compact.

Comment: Your answer seems to be right.